# Neat way to parse boolean or string args in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Looking for a clean and clever way to code the following:

`'true'` and `true` return `'true'`

`'false'`, `false`, `''`, and `undefined` return `'false'`

Comment: What about everything else?  Or are you sure only those values will be used as input.

Comment: The question doesn't cover `null` in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var getBoolAsString = function (x) {
  if (x === 'false' || !x) {
    return 'false';
  } else {
    return 'true';
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle test cases](http://jsfiddle.net/53DkV/)

The above covers the cases you've posted, as well as returning `'false'` for other falsy values like `null` and `zero`, `'true'` otherwise.

Though this seems like an antipattern.  Why do you need the boolean value as a string?

Comment: it gets added to a string for passing through an api. So I can actually rely on the type coercion.

Comment: @TinyTimZamboni Ah, API's.  Bane of my existence.  Don't forget to accept!

Comment: couldn't this also be: (x === 'false' || !x) ? 'false' : 'true'

Comment: Yes, it could, though I tend to be more verbose/explicit when answering SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isKindaTruth(val) {
   var truthValues = ['true', true];
   var falseValues = ['false', false, '', undefined];

   if (truthValues.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
     return 'true';
   }

   if (falseValues.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
     return 'false';
   }

   function ValueException(message) {
     this.message = message;
     this.name = "ValueException";
   }

   throw new ValueException("Value of " + val + " is not expected or wanted.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I actually ended up doing:

`var output = 'api parameter=' + !(!input || input === 'false')`